# jQuery not updating select list in Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamically created button and when clicked I want a select list in the modal to be updated. All the buttons are created, the modal works and the console messages ("Appending ..." and "Done!") under the "shown.bs.modal" event handler are being printed out.

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = $("#tableContainer");

    $("#seatPlayerModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        console.log("Appending ...");
        $("#player_select").append($("<option></option>").val(1).html("One"));
        $("#player_select").append($("<option></option>").val(2).html("Two"));
        $("#player_select").append($("<option></option>").val(3).html("Three"));
        console.log("Done!");
    });

    function drawSeat(seat) {
        if (seat.PlayerName == null)
        {
            var id = "seat-" + seat.Id;
            element.append("<button type='button' id = '" + id + "' class='seat-player btn btn-mdb'>Seat Player</button>");
            var button = $("#" + id);
            button.click(function () {
                $("#seatPlayerModal").modal('show');
            });
        }
        else
            element.append("<button type='button' class='seat-player btn btn-mdb'>Some player name ...</button>");
    };

    function drawTable(table) {
        element.append('<div id="' + table.Id + '"><h2 class="m-t-2">' + table.Name + '</h2></div>');
        $.each(table.Seats.Data, function (key, value) {
            drawSeat(value)
        });
    };

    function onSuccessGetTables(tables) {
        $.each(tables.Data, function (key, value) {
            drawTable(value);
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        getTables(onSuccessGetTables)
    }); 
</script>
```

The modal (which is in the same file):

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="seatPlayerModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Choose Player to be Seated</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="seatPlayerForm">
                    <!-- Seat Id -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="0" />

                    <!-- Selected Player Id -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="SelectedPlayerId" name="SelectedPlayerId" value="0" />

                    <!-- Player List -->
                    <select id="player_select"></select>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Seat Player</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea why the select list isn't being updated. When I run the code, although simplified, in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fe65o1s6/) it works. I have checked the names for typos but can't find anything and jQuery doesn't print out any error.

Comment: Is it because you're only wiring up one of your buttons?

Comment: When I click on all the buttons the modal popup so that part works. The part that doesn't work is populating the select list in the modal which should be done in the "shown" event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used `selectize` without knowing it.

Now I add items like this:

```
var accounts = $("#accounts")[0].selectize;
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            accounts.addOption({
                text: value.Name,
                value: value.Id
            });
        })
```